# Cassandra clustering with timestamp doesn't work as expected if the primary key contains (timeuuid and timestamp)

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm using Cassandra 2.1.5.

I'm creating table using:

```
create table dummy2(  
  id timeuuid,  
  time timestamp,  
  primary key (id, time) 
) with clustering order by (time desc);
```

I inserted into the table four records:

```
insert into dummy2 (id, time) values (now(), 1000000);  
insert into dummy2 (id, time) values (now(), 2000000);  
insert into dummy2 (id, time) values (now(), 3000000);  
insert into dummy2 (id, time) values (now(), 4000000);
```

I get results:

```
 id                                   | time  
--------------------------------------+--------------------------  
 e1fa7a80-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1970-01-01 08:33:20+0800  
 e3bbb280-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1970-01-01 08:50:00+0800  
 e5ceb400-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1970-01-01 09:06:40+0800  
 e0719090-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1970-01-01 08:16:40+0800
```

which looks like a tree map order, or random...

If I change the id type from "timeuuid" to "text", then the ordering works just fine:

```
 id    | time
-------+--------------------------
 hello | 1970-01-01 09:06:40+0800
 hello | 1970-01-01 08:50:00+0800
 hello | 1970-01-01 08:33:20+0800
 hello | 1970-01-01 08:16:40+0800
```

Is it by design or a bug? Or I'm using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the way Cassandra is designed to work.  Clustering order only works *within* a partition.  That's because each partition key is hashed into a token to determine where it should be stored in the cluster (to provide optimal data distribution).  The rows within each partition are then written on-disk in their clustering order.

So in your first example, each row is sorted by `time` within each id.  Of course, as each partition key (`id`) is different, you have no way of seeing that.  But in your second example, your partition keys are the same, so your results are clustered by time.

> "which looks like a tree map order, or random..."

They are ordered by their hashed token values, you can see this by using the `token` function:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT token(id),id,time FROM dummy3;

 token(id)            | id    | time
----------------------+-------+--------------------------
 -3758069500696749310 | hello | 1969-12-31 19:06:40-0600
 -3758069500696749310 | hello | 1969-12-31 18:50:00-0600
 -3758069500696749310 | hello | 1969-12-31 18:33:20-0600
 -3758069500696749310 | hello | 1969-12-31 18:16:40-0600

(4 rows)
```

Or perhaps a better example:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT token(id),id,time FROM dummy2;

 token(id)            | id                                   | time
----------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------
 -5795426230130619993 | e1fa7a80-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1969-12-31 18:33:20-0600
 -2088884548269216731 | e3bbb280-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1969-12-31 18:50:00-0600
  8496311684589314797 | e5ceb400-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1969-12-31 19:06:40-0600
  8930307282139899213 | e0719090-1e64-11e5-8bf5-55cdf06f740f | 1969-12-31 18:16:40-0600

(4 rows)
```

Earlier this year I wrote an article for PlanetCassandra on this frequently mis-understood topic: [We Shall Have Order!](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)  Give it a read and see if that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question and further explaining the details. Really helpful. I'll have a read on your article to see how this could apply to my design.